# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error' what(): basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I have been trying to read cfg into a multilinklist but im getting this error please someone help. It keeps on giving this error. I dont think there's any error. Please check this code and tell me where is the error which causes the program to crash with the exception attached in the picture

---

> ```
>  #include <iostream>
>     #include <fstream>
>     #include <cstring>
>
>     using namespace std;
>
>     struct prod_list{
>
>        string production;
>      struct prod_list *next;
>
>     }*head_p=NULL;
>
>     //Node for linked list to store Non terminals
>
>     struct rule_list{
>
>       char non_terminal;
>       struct prod_list *first;
>       struct rule_list *next;
>
>     }*head_r=NULL;
>
>     // Global variable
>        struct prod_list *temp_p,*prev_p=NULL,*first_p=NULL,*temp1_p=NULL,*temp2_p,*newTemp;
>        struct rule_list *temp_r,*prev_r=NULL,*first_r=NULL ,*temp1_r=NULL;
>
>
>
>     prod_list *adding_productions_of_the_rule(string line);
>     prod_list *add_node(prod_list *root, string production);
>
>
>     int main()
>     {
>
>     string line;
>
>     ifstream file ("cfg.txt");
>     if (file.is_open())
>     {
>       while ( getline (file,line) )
>       {
>             head_p = NULL;
>
>             // Creating rule_list node
>             temp_r = new rule_list;
>             temp_r->non_terminal = line[0];
>             head_p = adding_productions_of_the_rule(line);
>             temp_r->first = head_p;
>             temp_r->next = NULL;
>
>             if(head_r == NULL)
>             {
>                 head_r = temp_r;
>                 prev_r  = temp_r;
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 prev_r->next = temp_r;
>                 prev_r = temp_r;
>             }
>
>
>       }
>       file.close();
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         cout << "Unable to open file";
>     }
>
>     return 0;
>     }
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>     prod_list *adding_productions_of_the_rule(string line)
>     {
>
>             string prod = NULL;
>
>             // Splitting line after arrow in cfg rule line.
>             line = line.substr(3,line.length());
>             // cout << "The cfg is "+line << endl;
>
>             // declaring character array of line's length
>             char ch[line.length()]={0};
>             // memset(ch,'0',line.length());
>             // cout << sizeof(ch) << endl;
>
>
>             // storing line in character array and printing character array
>             for(int i=0; i<line.length(); i++){
>                 ch[i] = line[i];
>                 // Displaying the characters stored in character array from string line.
>                 // cout << ch[i];
>             }
>             // cout << endl;
>
>             char *point;
>             point = strtok(ch, "|");
>             while(point != NULL){
>
>                  // cout << point << endl;
>
>                 // Assigning each production from the cfg rule to an array of strings
>                 // production[i] = point;
>                 // cout << production[i] << endl;
>
>
>                 // Creating prod_list node
>                 prod = point;
>                 head_p = add_node( head_p, prod );
>
>
>                 point = strtok(NULL, "|");
>                 // i++;
>
>             }
>
>
>             return head_p;
>     }
>
>
>
>
>
>
>     prod_list *add_node(prod_list *root, string production){
>
>
>     prod_list *next_ptr = NULL;
>     prod_list *prev_ptr = NULL;
>
>     if(root == NULL){
>         //list is empty
>         if( (root = new prod_list) != NULL){
>             next_ptr = root;
>             // cin >> next_ptr->title;
>             next_ptr->production = production;
>             next_ptr->next = NULL;
>
>         }else{
>             cout << "Error: Unable to allocate memory. " << endl;
>             return NULL;
>         }
>         return next_ptr;
>     }else{
>         //list has members.
>         next_ptr = root;
>         while(next_ptr->next != NULL){
>             next_ptr = next_ptr->next;
>         }
>         prev_ptr = next_ptr;
>
>         if((next_ptr = new prod_list)!= NULL){
>             prev_ptr->next = next_ptr;
>             next_ptr->production = production;
>             next_ptr->next = NULL;
>         }else{
>             cout << "Error: Unable to allocate memory " << endl;
>         }
>
>     }
>     return root;
>     }
> ```
>
> **I have been trying to read cfg into a multilinklist but im getting this error please someone help **

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgNXB.png

Comment: See that Debug the program button? Could come in handy...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error an be reduced to a very minimal case:

```
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::string prod = NULL;
}
```

What's happening is this is trying to make a `std::string` out of a NULL pointer. Obviously there is nothing there for the `string` to work with, so it did the only thing it could do: scream for help.

Solution:

Don't assign anything. `std::string` will default construct an empty string.